# LISP car of the last element?

Tags: lisp, warnings, clisp

LISP stumps me yet again... Why can't I get the value of the last element in a list? I have a list set up similar to this:

```
(setq bar '(((1 2) 3 4 5)((6 7) 8 9 10)))
```

Now I get a return of 4 for:

```
(caddar bar)
```

There is a return of (5) for:

```
(cdddar bar)
```

But I can't get a 5 for:

```
(cadddar bar)
```

Why is this--and how do I get the value of the 5?

Error:

```
; Warning: This function is undefined:
;   CADDDAR

Error in KERNEL:%COERCE-TO-FUNCTION:  the function CADDDAR is undefined.
[Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The functions with 5 or more a's and d's are not defined.  Only 4 and fewer.  There are too many possible functions of that length for it be be practical.

You have to just spell it out:
`(car (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (car x))))))`

Comment: The answer was: (car (cdddar lst)).... now why this != cadddar, I do not understand.

Comment: Somewhere deep within the bowels of your LISP implementation are:
(defun cadr (x) ...)
(defun cdar (x) ...)
(defun caar (x) ...)
(defun cddr (x) ...)
and so on for all the combinations of 'a' and 'd' of length 1 through 4.  The spec does not include the ones of length 5 as there are too many.  There is nothing special about the #'cdadr family of functions.  They are not parsed on interpreted uniquely.  They are just normal functions.  You are more than welcome to (defun ...) some new ones to fill in gaps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, per the error message, there is no `cadddar` function. Keep in mind that `car` and `cdr` are the primitive list-reading functions. Others like `caddar` are convenience functions that are built from a combination of one or more `car` and `cdr`. That is, you could perform list manipulation just fine with only `car` and `cdr` if `caddar` etc. didn't exist, the extended functions just make your life a bit easier.

So, the way to approach this is to synthesize your own `cadddar` using `car` and `cdr`. If it isn't immediately apparent how to do this, start simplier (with, say, `cadr` or `cdar`) and build up to `cadddar`.

Answer (score 2):

The functions with more than 4 `a`s and `d`s aren't defined by the standard, maybe because there are 32 of them [and it gets exponentially messier from then on].

A sure-fire way to get the last element of a list: `last` returns the last cons cell, so

```
(car (last list))
```

gives you the last list element. Of course, `list` could be something else like `(first list)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(first (last (first '(((1 2) 3 4 5) ((6 7) 8 9 10)))))

-> 5
```